# Create data frame containing the row position of missing values

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na, missing-data

I would like to create a table that contains the row position of missing values from an original data frame. This would essentially take the first table as input and create the table below that one.

[image]

I know that I can use apply in order to create a list with this row position but I am struggling to then take that list and make a dataframe.

```
# Minimum working example

# Create dataset
data0 <- data.frame("A" = c(NA,NA,1,1), "B"= c(1,NA,1,1),"C"= c("john","john",NA,NA),"D"= c("john","john","john","john"))

# Create list of all rows containing missing values for a particular column then print as dataframe

list1<-apply(is.na(data0), 2, which)

> print(list1)
$A
[1] 1 2

$B
[1] 2
$C
[1] 3 4
$D
integer(0)

# Turn list1 to a data.frame leading to answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `list` with `sapply`, assign the `length` to `nrow` of 'data0', to append `NA` at the end where there are less elements and wrap with `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(sapply(list1, `length<-`, nrow(data0)))
```

-output

```
  A  B  C  D
1  1  2  3 NA
2  2 NA  4 NA
3 NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA
```

---

We could also do this as

```
library(dplyr)
data0 %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(rep(NA_integer_, n()), 
         is.na(.), which(is.na(.)))[order(!is.na(.))]))
   A  B  C  D
1  1  2  3 NA
2  2 NA  4 NA
3 NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA
```

---

If we don't need to order the values, i.e. the positions remain in the same position of occcurence

```
NA^(!is.na(data0)) * row(data0)
      A  B  C  D
[1,]  1 NA NA NA
[2,]  2  2 NA NA
[3,] NA NA  3 NA
[4,] NA NA  4 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` and starting from `data0` you can do -

```
sapply(data0, function(x) which(is.na(x))[seq_along(x)])

#      A  B  C  D
#[1,]  1  2  3 NA
#[2,]  2 NA  4 NA
#[3,] NA NA NA NA
#[4,] NA NA NA NA
```